# Reponse Preflight and Request header not allowed in Angular 2

Tags: wcf, angular

I am Working on Angular 2 for getting data from WCF service.
I am calling Login method that returns a token.

For fetching Project Data i am using GET method and in that request we need to pass token in header.

But it gives Error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.149/API/Service1.svc/Datalist. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect). Request header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

This are my Headers:-

```
General:
Request URL:http://pct149/ITM_API/Service1.svc/BHL/Projects

Request Method:OPTIONS

Status Code:200 OK

Remote Address:192.168.0.149:80
```

**Here is my Angular Service in which i am calling WCF Service:-**

```
   import {Injectable} from "@angular/core"

   import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from "@angular/http"

   import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

   import {HttpClient } from "@service/http-client";

   @Injectable()

   export class AppService {
         Hero = [];

        baseUrl = "http://pct149/ITM_API/Service1.svc/BHL/";

        constructor(private _http: Http, private httpClient: HttpClient) {
        }

        Authentication() {
             return this._http.get(this.baseUrl +        "Login/harshad.bhola@server1.com/1")
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let dataToken = response.json();
            let Token = dataToken.Token;
            if (Token != null & dataToken != null) {
                return Token;
            }
            else {
                return '';
            }
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

       loadProjects(Token) {

         return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "Projects", { headers: {  'token': Token.trim() } })
        .map((responseData: Response) => {
              let appData = responseData.json();
              console.log(appData);
              return appData;
          });
    }

       private handleError(error: Response) {
         console.error(error);
         return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
```

}

**Here is my Component from where i am calling service method:-**

```
     import {Component} from "@angular/core";

     import { RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouterModule, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from "@angular/router";

     import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, HTTP_BINDINGS } from '@angular/http';

     import {AppService } from "@service/app.service";

     @Component({
        selector: 'app',
        templateUrl: 'htmls/app.html',
        directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
        providers: [AppService]
     })

    export class ProjectListComponent {
           Projects = [];
           result = '';

    constructor(private _appService: AppService) {
       this.GetProject();
    }

     GetProject() {
       this._appService.Authentication().subscribe(result =>  {this._appService.loadProjects(result).subscribe(newProject => this.Projects = newProject); });
  }
}
```

**Below Code i put in Global.asax of My WCF Service:-**

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Please Help me if i am Wrong.

Comment: Don't you need to add `token` in your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`? Like: `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, token");`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add options to your list of supported methods in your CORS enablement. I'm using webapi 2 so I do this:

from webApiConfig.cs:

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS");
```

I also had to trap the preflight request and add the required header:
from global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
   var req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
   var res = HttpContext.Current.Response;

   var val = res.Headers.GetValues("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
   if (val == null)
   {
      if (!req.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("token") || (req.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("token") && req.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS"))
      {
         res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
      }
   }



   if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
   {
      res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name");
      res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS");



      res.StatusCode = 200;
      res.End();
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps.